# How to select values from row with maximum date for multiple id matches

Tags: oracle

I'm not sure my title makes the question I am asking very clear.  I am using an SQL Developer to query an Oracle database.  I have contructed the query below which is able to pull the values I require for one specific ID.  I need a query that will pull the same values but for multiple ids.  I will need to run the same query on a monthly basis for a varying set of 20-50 ids.  The database contains 80,000+ ids so I do not want to pull everything if I can avoid it. Is this possible?

```
SELECT b.id, a.final_grade, a.final_score
FROM db.table1 a, db.table2 b
where a.survey_id=b.survey_id
and b.id = '1796'
and a.created_dt = (select max (a.created_dt) from db.table1 a, db.table2 b 
where a.survey_id=b.survey_id and b.cp_id = '1796')
```

thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Sorry, for my unclear question.  Every id in the database is given a new grade and a new score every year.  the data the new grade/score is assigned varies for every id.  I am looking to select the most recent grade and score for a specific group of ids.

Comment: Oh, and the last line of the query I posted should say b.id NOT b.cp_id

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use ROW_NUMBER() and a WITH clause.

```
with data as 
SELECT 
      b.id, 
      a.final_grade, 
       a.final_score,
       ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY b.id, order by a.created_dt desc) rn
FROM 
        db.table1 a
        INNER JOIN  db.table2 b
        ON  a.survey_id=b.survey_id

where
 b.id in (<Comma seperated list of ids>)
)

SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE rn = 1
```

Note: if there are ties for created_dt for a given id an arbitrary row will be selected. If you instead want ties to be displayed replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `RANK()`

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT b.id, a.final_grade, a.final_score
    FROM db.table1 a, db.table2 outerb
    where a.survey_id=outerb.survey_id
    and outerb.id IN (<SELECT query with your list of ids>)
    and a.created_dt = (select max (a.created_dt) from db.table1 a, db.table2 b 
    where a.survey_id=b.survey_id and b.cp_id = outerb.id )
```

Is that what you are looking for? Question is not clear!

Comment: Note that `b` is aliased twice. Once in the main select an again in the sub select. Which `b` do you think is be referenced in `and b.cp_id = b.id`

Comment: I'm afraid this does not yield any results for me. I apologize if my imprecise question caused confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what your looking for or at least this is what i got with your explanation:

```
SELECT b.id, a.final_grade, a.final_score
    FROM db.table1 a, db.table2 b
    where a.survey_id=b.survey_id
    and b.id IN (<SELECT query with your list of ids>)
    and a.created_dt **IN** (select max (a.created_dt) from db.table1 a, db.table2 b 
    where a.survey_id=b.survey_id and b.cp_id = b.id )
```